# Confusion regarding 2-body problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, celestial-mechanics

I'm new to 2-body problems, especially the case of binary stars, or a planet around a star system, and I'm facing this small doubt. I know, that in order to solve this, we mostly reduce this 2-body problem into a corresponding 1-body problem, using reduced mass.

However, in some places, I've seen one of the bodies is considered stationary, and then reduced mass is used to find motion about this first body. So, we have considered our first body to be the frame of reference.

In some questions, however, I've seen the barycenter taken to be the reference frame, and both bodies' motion calculated with respect to it.

Are these two approaches different, or is the barycenter approach just an extension of the first approach ? Are we first calculating the motion of one body around another, and then calculating both their motions about the bary-center, or are these approaches absolutely different ?

Comment: Could you point to the place where you saw one of the bodies being stationary?

Comment: @LucasBaldo its on wikipedia. It basically says "Thus we have reduced our problem to a single degree of freedom, and we can conclude that particle 1 moves with respect to the position of particle 2 as a single particle of mass equal to the reduced mass, $\mu $."

Comment: See my answer to this related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/599329/how-does-the-orbital-motion-of-reduced-mass-tell-us-how-the-individual-planets-s?rq=1

Comment: @GiorgioP Thank you so much ! As a matter of fact I was just checking that answer.

Comment: I failed to find that quote on Wikipedia, but it's page on [two-body problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem) does mention this reduction to one-body. There however, it states that this is just an approximation, which is suitable when the masses are significantly different.

Comment: @StephenG yes it does, thanks ! The problem is, most material I've seen, leave that problem after calculating $r$. This creates a lot of confusion, as we are getting to know that one body moves around the other body in an ellipse. However, without calculating $r_1$ and $r_2$ we cannot find the exact motion of the bodies.  Thank you so much, again.